# reordering list of dicts arbitrarily in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 4 dicts (always 4) that look something like this:

```
[{'id':'1','name':'alfa'},{'id':'2','name':'bravo'},{'id':'3','name':'charlie'},{'id':'4','name':'delta'}]
```

I know exactly the order I want them in, which is:

```
2, 3, 1, 4
```

what's the simplest way of reordering them?

Comment: I think you'll like my update, I can't imagine it getting any simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's always four, and you always know the order, just simply like this:

```
lst = [{...},{...},{...},{...}]
ordered = [lst[1],lst[2],lst[0],lst[3]]
```

If you meant to sort them by 'id', in that order:

```
ordered = sorted(lst, key=lambda d: [2,3,1,4].index(int(d['id'])))
```

Note that `index()` is `O(n)` but doesn't require you to build a dictionary. So for small inputs, this may actually be faster. In your case, there are four elements, ten comparisons are guaranteed.  Using `timeit`, this snippet runs 10% faster than the dictionary based solution by tokland... but it doesn't really matter since neither will likely be significant.

Comment: thanks - forgot about indexes, I was calling the first item 1 etc hence it through a index out of range error.

Comment: Isn't this code calling list.index (O(n)) for each element in the lst to be ordered? it won't perform well with large lists.

Comment: @tokland : Yes, it's `O(n)` on 4 elements.  Max of 16.  I suppose that's worthy of a downvote... but his question was solved by the first solution.

Comment: @Stephen, I thought that was the way to go, downvote but reasoning why. But I am sorry it upset you, but I cannot remove the vote unless the question is edited. Which one was the first solution? Alex Martelli's?

Comment: @tokland : I appreciate that you reasoned why.  I'm not upset that you downvoted me... I just wanted to point out that you're arguing an asymptotic complexity with a constant 4 elements.  Asymptotic complexity is for larger (or variable sized) inputs, he guaranteed 4 elements.  For something that small, it's usually faster to avoid building a O(1) data structure.  I added a note that this was linear , but I benchmarked it as faster than your solution.

Comment: What I meant by "the first solution" was what I wrote to reorder the tuple elements (before I suggested using index). As far as overall answer ordering, Matt Joiner was first, I was second to answer.  You can see this by sorting the answers by "oldest".

Comment: Is it possible to order by alphabetical list, instead of shuffling with index values?

Comment: ^ I removed the int() in at the very end and it worked!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pretty general function to impose a wanted order (any key value not in the wanted order is placed at the end of the resulting list, in arbitrary sub-order):

```
def ordered(somelist, wantedorder, keyfunction):
    orderdict = dict((y, x) for x, y in enumerate(wantedorder))
    later = len(orderdict)
    def key(item):
        return orderdict.get(keyfunction(item), later)
    return sorted(somelist, key=key)
```

You'd be using it as

```
import operator
sortedlist = ordered(dictlist, ('2', '3', '1', '4'),
                     operator.itemgetter('id'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
the_list.sort(key=lambda x: (3, 1, 2, 4)[int(x["id"])-1])
```

### Update0

A new much simpler answer

```
the_list = [the_list[i - 1] for i in (2, 3, 1, 4)]
```

This way the OP can see his desired ordering, and there's no silliness with sorting, which is not required here. It's probably fast too.

Comment: I might add that although this is complex for some people, looking at the other answers, this one is probably both faster and more straightforward.

Comment: The array (3, 1, 2, 4) is indexed into using the `id - 1` of the dicts, to get the order you requested.

Answer (score 2):

A non-generalized solution:

```
lst = [{'id':'1','name':'alfa'},{'id':'2','name':'bravo'},{'id':'3','name':'charlie'},{'id':'4','name':'delta'}]
order = ["2", "3", "1", "4"]
indexes = dict((idfield, index) for (index, idfield) in enumerate(order))
print sorted(lst, key=lambda d: indexes[d["id"]])
# [{'id': '2', 'name': 'bravo'}, {'id': '3', 'name': 'charlie'}, {'id': '1', 'name': 'alfa'}, {'id': '4', 'name': 'delta'}]
```

And here generalized:

```
def my_ordered(it, wanted_order, key):
    indexes = dict((value, index) for (index, value) in enumerate(wanted_order))
    return sorted(it, key=lambda x: indexes[key(x)])

import operator  
print my_ordered(lst, order, operator.itemgetter("id"))
```

Comment: Well, this appears just to be Alex Martelli's answer without taking in account elements in input but not in wanted_order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-order without regard for content of the dicts:

```
>>> order = 2, 3, 1, 4
>>> d = [{'id':'1','name':'alfa'},{'id':'2','name':'bravo'},{'id':'3','name':'charlie'},{'id':'4','name':'delta'}]
>>> index = dict(enumerate(dd))
>>> [index[i-1] for i in order]
[{'id': '2', 'name': 'bravo'}, {'id': '3', 'name': 'charlie'}, {'id': '1', 'name': 'alfa'}, {'id': '4', 'name': 'delta'}]
```

If you want to base your sorting on the `'id'` of the dicts:

```
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda x: order.index(int(x['id'])))
[{'id': '2', 'name': 'bravo'}, {'id': '3', 'name': 'charlie'}, {'id': '1', 'name': 'alfa'}, {'id': '4', 'name': 'delta'}]
```