# Sorting list of dictionaries according to specific order

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, mapping

I am using Python 2.6 and I have two data stores. Querying the first one returns a list of document IDs in a specific order. I look up all the documents at once in the second data store using these IDs, which returns a list of dictionaries (one for each doc), but not in the same order as the original list. I now need to re-sort this list of dictionaries so that the documents are in the order that their IDs were in the first list. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: I'm bracing myself for a mind-blowing solution...

Comment: Sooo .. Does your data store not support joins, or do you not know joins?

Comment: Did you check this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301406/reordering-list-of-dicts-arbitrarily-in-python

Comment: THC4k, as I pointed out in my question, these are separate data stores. Alas, no join is possible.

tokland, thank you for the reference, I didn't find it when I first searched the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best (and general) solution seems to be given here: [reordering list of dicts arbitrarily in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301406/reordering-list-of-dicts-arbitrarily-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

Don't.

Move your "list of dictionaries (one for each doc), but not in the same order as the original list" into a dictionary.

This new dictionary-of-dictionaries has the matching key.

Then go through your first list in it's order and find items in the dictionary-of-dictionaries that match.

```
some_list= query_data_store_1()
some_other_list= query_data_store_2( some_list )

dict_of_dict = dict( (d['key'], d) for d in some_other_list )

for item in some_list:
    other_item = dict_of_dict[ item['key'] ]

    # Now you have item from the first list matching item from the second list.
    # And it's in order by the first list.
```

Comment: dict_of_dict = dict( d['id'], d for d in some_other_list )

Answer (score 1):

You could build a separate dictionary mapping ids to positions and use that to order the documents:

```
ids = ...
positions = {}
for pos, id in enumerate(ids):
   positions[id] = pos

docs = ...
docs.sort(key=lambda doc: positions[doc['id']])
```